# Send verification email with firebase v9

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with sendiing a verification email with firebase authentication module. In previous version of firebase I used to do it like this:

```
 await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);

 await firebase.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification();
```

And with new version of firebase I need to do it like this:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendEmailVerification } from 'firebase/auth';
...
const auth = getAuth();

await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

await sendEmailVerification()
```

Problem is that Typescript forces me to pass a parameter of type User to sendEmailVerification, and I don't know where should i get this user parameter from. I tried returning something from createUserWithEmailAndPassword but Typescript says that it's a wrong type. So my question is how to get this user object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to pass the [`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authcurrentuser) that exists within `auth`, something like below should work:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendEmailVerification } from 'firebase/auth';
...
const auth = getAuth();

await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

await sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
```

Answer (score 2):

To send a verification email with Firebase `v9`, you can use the `sendEmailVerification()` method.

To use it, you can just use the code below. It will send the user a verification email once he/she has created an account.

*Note: With the code below, `auth`, `email`, and `password` are assuming that they are `!undefined`.*

```js
await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((cred) => await sendEmailVerification(cred.user));
```

After running the code above (with the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method), it should send the user a verification email.

---

For more information, visit the [official Firebase `v9` documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) about sending email verifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((cred) => await sendEmailVerification(cred.user))

await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((cred) => await sendEmailVerification(cred))
```

Either one of these should work.

Comment: I wouldn't mix await and promise chaining.